# How to drive a speaker/microphone from a digital circuit?

Tags: microphone, speakers, wave, synthesizer

I’m having a hard time understanding how to use speakers or microphones. My end game here is a sequencer

I’m going to lay out what I think so that you guys can correct me and help me understand why I’m wrong.

Suppose I built a square wave generator from a Schmitt Trigger using 5 V. From what I understand, the output will fluctuate between 0 V and 5 V.

But from my extremely limited understanding of speakers, as analog components they should “rest” at 0 V and fluctuate below and above 0. But isn’t voltage relative? Couldn’t we just “say” that 2.5 V is ground, and the oscillator actually fluctuates between -2.5 V and 2.5 V? How would I “set” that?

I’ve also heard that you have to use a coupling capacitor to block the DC component. In this example - a square wave from 0 to 5 V, what’s the DC component?  And how would we pick that? If I’m using an 8 ohm speaker, with a range of about 200 Hz - 20 kHz, [this calculator](https://www.v-cap.com/coupling-capacitor-calculator.php) would suggest that I should use a 200 uF cap if I want the -3 dB frequency to be at 100. Does that sound right? I’ve also seen diagrams where there’s a resistor between the negative end of the cap and ground... why?

Is 5 V even enough to drive one of those tiny 8 ohm speakers? Do I need a higher voltage? How would I go about amplifying the output if I did need a higher voltage?

If I were to turn off the oscillator, it would rest at 0v. But, as I assumed earlier, wouldn’t the speaker have to rest at the reference voltage of 2.5 V? How would I go about doing that? Or if I wanted to turn down the amplitude?

If I wanted two tones playing - two frequencies - how would I add their wave forms?

I basically have no idea how to do anything and I can’t seem to find a guide that both shows the circuit AND explains it. 
I also have basically no idea how to use a mic.

Any explanations or links would be appreciated.

Comment: Note: "Sequencer" means something different to electronics designers than what it means to musicians.

Comment: If your goal is to build something that a musician can actually use, then you'll probably want a [line level output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_level) instead of a "tiny 8 ohm speaker."  Even if you do want a built-in speaker, you'll probably want a built-in amplifier too, so that you're not driving it directly from a logic-level output pin.

Comment: @jameslarge Thanks! Yes, I planned to do something like that in the future, but for now I want to get the basics down!

Comment: You can save yourself some trouble if you use a part like the [LM386 Audio Amplifier](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/texas-instruments/LM386N-1-NOPB/296-44414-5-ND/6284), and build the circuit shown in the data sheet as a "typical application."

Comment: @jameslarge Excellent pointer, thank you! The Vin in this case – could this just be directly the output of the 0v-5v Schmitt trigger oscillator? Or would I have to do the DC Biasing step before like someone else said?

Comment: The LM386 has ground-referenced inputs and automatically biases the output for you to mid supply, so you should be good to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The speaker moves both ways, this is why you want it to rest at 0V.  Otherwise you are only ever pushing on the speaker and never pulling on it (or vice versa).  This works, but you are not using your speaker optimally.

The series capacitor with resistor to ground form a high pass filter (which blocks DC and idles at 0V).  Now you can DC bias your signal so it idles at 2.5V.  The high pass filter blocks the DC, so on the speaker side of the filter it is idling at 0V.  This way your signal both pushes and pulls on the speaker.

To answer if 5V is enough to drive your speaker, we would first need to know how much power you are expecting.  To find the RMS value of your 0-5V signal:
Vrms=0.707∗5V=3.5V

And since power is voltage squared over resistance:
(3.5V * 3.5V) / 8Ω = 1.53W

Your question about adding two sources should be a separate question.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I looked up high pass filter, and [this diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELJkc.gif) and [this one](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/filter/fil39.gif) seem to suggest that adding the filter does shift it from 0v:5v to -5v:5v. Is this true? Would I even need the DC bias in that case?

Comment: Not quite.  As you posted, voltage is relative.  You still have a 5V signal, however, on the speaker side of the filter that would be -2.5V to +2.5V.  Without the DC bias, your signal will never 'pull' on the capacitor and only 'push'.

Comment: I want to point out that what I wrote about the DC bias is not strictly true, and is an oversimplification.  Your circuit will work without the bias but an adequate explanation of how how the A/C signal is truly affected by the filter is beyond the scope of this question/answer.

Answer (score 0):

Bulding on evildemonic answer, once the dc-blocking capacitor is added, you need a variable duty-cycle voltage to pull the speaker one way or the other from the +2.5v average output.

PWM or Pulse Width Modulation is a digital method. Read all about it.

Comment: Thanks! I'm familiar with PWM, but I wanted to try to learn how to do things the analog way. I also wanted to do this without any microcontrollers. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to trying to mix things which are in different hierarchy levels in the foeld of electronic music.

A sequencer = Computing device or a piece of software which stores music information and plays it (=what notes are played, by which instruments they are played, when, how hard, with which sound adjusting, articulation and effect parameters)

An instrument = Device which generates sound waveforms from inputted music information. That information can be inputted by pressing keys (like a oiano or other real time performing interface) and turning the controllers  or it can be supplied as a data stream by a sequencer .

Today electronic instruments have the following major principles

- Analog synthesizers are analog computers that are controlled via D/A converters by a computer that in real time interpret the performance keys & controllers or the music information data stream
- Sample based synthesizers and sample players have instead of an analog computer a normal computer that reads the waveforms + their sound processing receipes from the memory. The stored waveforms can be for example recorded real instrument voices. The result is outputted via D/A converter or as standardized digital audio data stream. It's very different than the musical information data stream.
- Algorithmic synthesizers which compute the sound waveforms instead of taking it from sample storage.

If you want to connect a speaker, you probably want to make an instrument. Have a DA converter or program it  with the pulse width modulation. Have a capacitor to block the DC which is harmful to the speaker.

Have a program which generates the sound waveform data or takes it from memory. The program outputs it to the DA converter. Someone must send to that program messages which tell what waveforms to play, how hard, at what pitch frequency and what is the wanted processing.

Have a program which tells to the preceding program the wanted output as musical information.

ADDED due a comment:

The sequenced music pioneers Kraftwerk, Tangerine Dream,  W.Carlos and Mr.Jarre (maybe also Pink Floyd in smaller scale) had those pot row sequencers. The potentiometers were used to give control voltages for pitch volume, and filtering to Moog, Oberheim, Buchla etc...devices.  You should read about voltage controlled oscillators, amplifiers and filters.

Comment: Thanks! I want to avoid microcontrollers for this project, because as a programmer I have a tendency to do everything in code and nothing with actual components. Let me explain further what I want to make: imagine a row of 8 potentiometers and switches. A counter loops through 1 through 8, using the pot to adjust the pitch of the instrument generator. I'm also considering adding a voice sampler to the mix, allowing you one-hit samples.

Comment: @ThorCorreia I augmented the answer.